# What is the group $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}} { \mathbb{Q}{\bigl(\sqrt2, \sqrt3\,\bigr)}} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, automorphism-group

This question was given to us by instructor in class notes of Course on Field theory and there are no questions worked out in his notes which are posted online . So, I am looking for an explanation of his question which is solved( but explanation was not good).

Find group  $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}} { \mathbb{Q}{\bigl(\sqrt2, \sqrt3\,\bigr)}} $ ?

> Answer posted : let $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}} \bigl(\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt2, \sqrt3\,\bigr)\bigr) $ , then $\sigma$ is completely determined by $\sigma(\sqrt{2}\,)$ and $\sigma(\sqrt{3}\,)$.

Why so? Which result is used?

> (solution continued) Only possibility is $\sigma(\sqrt2\,) = \sqrt2, -\sqrt2 \:$ and $\sigma(\sqrt3\,) =\sqrt3, -\sqrt3$.

Again no reasoning is given!!

> So, there are 4-distinct $\Bbb Q$-homomorphisms (understood).

> And $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}\bigl(\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)\bigr) $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 × \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Why not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

I have asked 3 questions but I could really not understand the problem after trying to think a lot and I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Every element of the field can be expressed in terms of $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$, so if you know what $\sigma$ does to them, then you know what $\sigma$ does to everything. $2=\sigma(2)=\sigma((\sqrt2)^2)=(\sigma(\sqrt2))^2$. Since you know what the automorphisms are, you can check they all have order two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First question*: $\sigma$ is completely determined by the images of $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ simply because any element in $\mathbf Q\bigl(\sqrt2,\sqrt 3\,\bigr)$ is a polynomial in $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$, and $\sigma$ is a ring  homomorphism.

*Second question*: the image of $\sqrt 2$ satisfies the same minimal equation, since $\sigma$ is a $\bf Q$-homomorphism. Same  reason for $\sqrt 3$.

*Last question*: The group of automorphisms can't be $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ because  no automorphism of this extension has order $4$, as the $\sigma^i(\sqrt 2\,)$ and the $\sigma^i(\sqrt 3)$ are roots of the quadratic polynomials $X^2-2 $ and $X^2-3$ respectively, and a quadratic polynomial has at most two roots.

Comment: in 2nd question why does image of √2 satisfies same minimal equation?

Comment: That's because for any polynomial $P$, one has $P\bigl(\sigma(\sqrt 2\,)\bigr)=\sigma\bigl(P(\sqrt 2\,)\bigr)$.

Comment: what if it was asked that find group $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Q \sqrt(2) \sqrt(3) \sqrt(5)}$. Then group would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \into \mathbb{Z}_2 \into \mathbb{Z}_2$. Am I right?

Comment: That's  not so obvious. We would have to check  that no root of one of these numbers lies in the subfield generated by the roots of the other two. I didn't check, but I believe it's probably true, and the same argument  would work.